# Unit testing OpenIdRelyingParty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, openid, dotnetopenauth

I apologize if this a duplicate question (I didn't find anything like that).
I'm trying to build an OpenId Authentication service and unit test it, currently I have the following setup:

```
public class OpenIdAuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
{
    private IConfigurationService   _configService;
    private OpenIdRelyingParty      _openIdRelyingParty;

    public OpenIdAuthenticationService(IConfigurationService configService)
    {
        _configService      = configService;
        _openIdRelyingParty = new OpenIdRelyingParty();            
    }
}
```

Apparently OpenIdRelyingParty requires access to HttpContext, is there a way to mock OpenIdRelyingParty and inject it the service ? Or maybe mock HttpContext and provide it to OpenIdRelyingParty somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock HttpContext for OpenIdRelyingParty you should modify the code of that class. Even you would waste some time mocking it due that it is a sealed class (but is not impossible you can use [MOCKWCF](http://wcfmock.codeplex.com/)).

I think that is better make a wrapper or adapter for  **OpenIdRelyingParty**. like:

```
public class OpenIdRelyingPartyWrapped
{
    private OpenIdRelyingParty openIdRelyingPartyTarget;
    ....
    public virtual IAuthenticationRequest CreateRequest(string text)
    {
        return this.openIdRelyingPartyTarget.CreateRequest(text);
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you will able to mock it as you want.

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach, but in this case, how would I initialize OpenIdRelyingParty ? Should I initialize it out of the wrapper and inject it ? Or should I check if it's null and define a default value ? Or I'm missing something ?

Comment: That depends on the strategy to make instances if you are using **IOC** you should keep that, then the injection would be by constructor or by a property. If you are not using IOC you can just make the instance in the constructor of **OpenIdRelyingPartyWrapped**.
For or your unit tests you should make a mock class that inherit from **OpenIdRelyingPartyWrapped** and override the methods that you want to mock.

Answer (score 1):

I would, since you are already doing it, inject `OpenIdRelyingParty` into your constructor as you are doing with your configuration service.

Barring that, you could mock the HttpContext in your unit test. `HttpContext.Current` has a setter, so set it to a mock/stub `HttpContextBase`. Here's an example using [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.com/) with NUnit:

```
[TearDown]
public void CleanUp()
{
    HttpContext.Current = null;
}

[Test]
public void FakeHttpContext()
{
    var context = Substitute.For<HttpContextBase>();
    var request = Substitute.For<HttpRequestBase>();
    context.Request.Returns(request);
    //Do any more arragement that you need.

    //Act

    //Assert
}
```

This to me would be a bit of a code smell though. It's testing dependencies of dependencies (or however far down that rabbit hole goes). It's useful though when refactoring isn't an option.

Comment: Thanks I can take the OpenIdRelyingParty out and inject it through the constructor, however how would I initialize it in my unit test ? It requires HttpContext and yet there is no way to provide it ?

Comment: @2Dim1 Inject an interface of it through the constructor, then mock the interface. That way no "real" implementation is used, and it will never hit the HttpContext.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Well to be honest I've tried that, however it appears that OpenIdRelyingParty is not the implementation of IOpenIdRelyingParty in DotNetOpenAuth ? Unless I'm missing something ?

Answer (score 1):

`OpenIdRelyingParty` can be used in unit tests by using the method overloads that accept an `HttpRequestBase`, which is totally mockable.  Only the methods that don't take that as a parameter require an `HttpContext.Current`.